# How to prevent user to leave a control if the value entered is not valid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to check for a value entered in a control (like an email, for example) and alert the user if this value already exists in the database. Is it possible to be done when user attempts to tab out of the control or I need to do it when form is submitted?

Comment: I think modern UX best practice would suggest you should let the user move out of the field (it would be pretty enraging not to), but mark fields with a clear "OK/NotOK" message.

Comment: @Pointy I think you are right. Thanks for the suggestion on best practices +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't. Don't. Don't. Just do NOT do this.
Do as said before and mark the field as invalid.

But if you **really need** to do this strange behavior, you can handle the blur event:

```
$("#MyId").on("blur", function(e) {

   if (shouldPreventMoveNext())
   {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      jQuery(this).focus();
      return false;
   }

});
```

The blur event is fired when the user is leaving the control.

Comment: I will do it on submit form then, as it seems to be the norm on the Web. But thanks for the good example. There is a lot of useful information on it.

Comment: I also see that the blur event can be used to set a default values when the user doesn't enter any or clear the existing one.

Comment: That's a better idea. You can trap the form submit using the `$("#form").on("submit", function(e) { })` and avoid submitting, perform aditional tasks or even prepare some ajax call instead the default submit behavior. Why don't you play a bit with jQuery.Validate?